# Does std::cout initialize (or pre-initialize) a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I have a question about pointers in C++.

I know you can't delete a uninitialized pointer and if you want to use **delete**, the pointer should be initialized first. But does **std::cout** somehow "initialize" it?

 If I try to run the code below it will crash during the execution.

```
#include <iostream>
int main (){
   int *ptr;
   delete ptr;
   return 0;
}
```

This is what I'd expect and I'm fine with it because the pointer is not initialized. However if I try to run the code below it won't crash!

```
#include <iostream>
int main (){
   int *ptr;
   std::cout << ptr << std::endl; //This is the new line
   delete ptr;
   return 0;
}
```

I know that the pointer **ptr** is not initialized because I can't assign anything to it, if I add this line before the **delete**

```
*ptr = 5;
```

The program will crash as expected.
Why, then the program won't crash if I use the **std::cout** before delete? I know **cout** didn't initialize the pointer, but is this somehow a "pre-initialization"(or something else)? 

Thanks!

Ezra

Comment: What does it print out? (Mine prints out 0x0) which is a null pointer. Passing a nullptr to delete is a nop. So basically you got lucky.

Comment: Reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, and how undefined behavior manifests itself is, well, undefined.

Comment: It's puzzling why it doesn't crash, however the behavior is undefined, which means anything can happen.

Comment: @FDinoff You cannot rely upon the pointer being null.

Comment: No, all that's happening here is that cout is printing a memory address -- nothing is being initialized.  By the way, MSVC will trigger a runtime assert if you try to run this in debug mode.

Comment: It prints the adress: 0x41657e;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting an uninitialized pointer is **undefined behavior.**

Undefined behavior *may* crash your program, if you are lucky.  You were *unlucky,* and your program did not crash.

In this case, when you call `delete ptr`, the compiler knows that the `ptr` is garbage.  Perhaps it just calls `delete` with whatever value is handy, and if you use `cout`, `nullptr` just coincidentally happens to be that value.

Comment: Dietrich, thanks for the answer.
And to everyone else who helped as well.  I didn't expect the answer would arrive so fast!

Comment: `cout << ptr` also causes undefined behaviour